# How to check that my method is called from inside '[UIView animateWithDuration:...]'?

Tags: animation, uiview, calayer, cgpath

I have a method that sets up UIView properties. And I call it directly in some cases and from `UIView animateWithDuration:` block. In this method I change among other things path of view's layer, so it works incorrectly with animation (path must be animated explicitly).

How can I determine that my method is called from inside `[UIView animateWithDuration:...]`?

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{ [myClass myMethod]; }];
...
- (void)myMethod
{
    if (__view_is_animating__) // how to check here?
    {...}
}
```

At current moment I set custom `viewIsAnimationFlag` before `[UIView animateWithDuration:...]` and check it in `myMethod` but it's rudely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to David Rönnqvist at [objc.io](http://www.objc.io/issue-12/view-layer-synergy.html):

"the view returns `NSNull` whenever the layer asks for an action *(animation handler for any animatable property)*, except when the property change happened inside of an animation block"

```
NSLog(@"we are inside animation block: %@",
    [myView actionForLayer:myView.layer forKey:@"position"] ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```